# In HTML5, is the <form> element a sectioning element, like <section>?

Tags: html, forms

In HTML5, some elements (like `<section>` and `<article>`) create a new sectioning context in the document‘s outline, as per the outlining algorithm.

This basically means that you can use `<h1>` as the top-level heading inside them without screwing up the document’s generated outline.

Does the `<form>` element create a sectioning context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because it’s not *[sectioning content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#sectioning-content)*. Only the following elements are sectioning content:

- `<article>`
- `<aside>`
- `<nav>`
- `<section>`

However, the `<fieldset>` element is a *sectioning root*. This means that it creates a new sectioning context (like a sectioning content element), *but* headings and sections within it don’t contribute to the outlines of their ancestors.

So you can blindly use `<h1>` inside a `<fieldset>` element without screwing up your document’s outline.

Sectioning roots are:

- `<blockquote>`
- `<body>`
- `<details>`
- `<dialog>`
- `<fieldset>`
- `<figure>`
- `<td>`

See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#headings-and-sections for a full description and examples.

Comment: Note: the new `dialog` element is also a sectioning root.